# Best practies CodeIgniter Templating

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter for few years for my PHP project.
Now I'm thinking how improve my view folder structure, using best practies.

I'll explain better. Basically I divide my webpage into 3 view:

- Header (/view/inc/header.php)
- SomeContent (/view/content_of_myView)
- Footer (/view/inc/footer.php)

My question is very simple: is this the best way? Or there are differents method to generate an header, maybe loading dinamycally all css/js assets with versioning? 
I don't want to use any template engine, sincerely I don't like very much.

Comment: i am also follow this structure ... but may be there are more better ways

Comment: check page roytuts.com/using-template-in-codeigniter-3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is okay, but I would put common elements in the root (header, footer). And the specific pages, elements goes into a folder, like:

`blog/index.php`, 
`blog/article.php`

The other thing what I want to implement, is to create a **MY_Controller.php**, and put a method in it, like `render`, which would be the following:

```
function render($view, $data) {
    $view['content'] = $this->load->view($view, $data, TRUE);
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $view, TRUE);
}
```

In this case you can put all the header and footer into one file, and just echo the `$content` variable in it.

For asset versioning, i suggest **gulp**, it's a build tool, you can concatanate, minify your assets, generate css from less or sass. And ofcourse, there are a packages for versioning, like this:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev

Comment: The snippet of this method should be: $this->render('inc/view', $somedata); ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I forgot to mention, in this case, you have to extend with MY_Controller, not CI_Controller